# How to access a folder via SMB protocol from ASP Net Core

Tags: asp.net-core, samba, smb

Hello i have a folder on a network that i can access via `SMB`.
I can connect through a linux bash using `Samba SMB Client` using:

`smbclient [IP] -U [user]` 
 --i am  required to enter password and then i have access.
I can then access the path.

I am trying to access the remote folder via a `ASP NET Core 3.1`  application hosted on linux and it seems i it does not see the folder:

```
var path="smb//[username]:[password]@\\[IP]\\[Path-to-remote-folder]"
var doesFolderExist=Directory.Exists(path);
```

I get a `false` but the folder exists and can be accessed from the `bash` with `smbclient` command.

How can i get access to the remote folder via `SMB` ?

Comment: In other words, you want to access a Windows file share from Linux. On Windows, you just type the path. On Linux, you mount the path. You don't need to run a client to connect in either case

Comment: I just said that i can access the folder with the client to state that the folder exists.I want to know why my  `Asp Net Core app`  using `System.IO.Directory.Exists()` can't find it.I need my app to access that folder !

Comment: And I posted a link to a duplicate question that shows how to *mount* the folder, just like any other network folder, instead of trying one-off access on each request. Or hard-coding the password in the application itself

Comment: What if I do not want to mount the folder?  Why so quick to close this?